# Destruir tag javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC estruturado da seguinte forma:

Na página `Home` existem vários `links` para outras `Actions` e `Controllers`, e os mesmos devolvem uma `PartialView` que monta todo o conteúdo em uma `modal`.

Até aí tudo bem, o problema é que ao fechar uma modal desse tipo, seus scripts continuam "vivos" de alguma forma. Logo, ao abrir uma nova modal que possua os mesmos elementos da modal aberta anteriormente, os scripts da modal que foi fechada são disparados na nova modal.


Existe alguma forma de "matar" definitivamente esses scripts?

Talvez pelo `id` da `tag` `<script id="scriptZumbi">`.

Comment: Acho que talvez esse não seja o caminho. Seria meio que uma gambiarra. Se você puder manipular o script e os modais sugiro que sete uma classe para cada modal e direcione o script para cada classe separadamente de acordo com o que você deseja. Ou então coloque os scripts dentro de cada partialview. Talvez se postar algum código eu possa ajudar melhor.

Comment: Essa modal é gerada dentro de uma div ou algo assim? Remova ela do seu código, assim também deixa a página mais leve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não. Tudo indica que seu código está recheado de más práticas.

Em primeiro lugar, uma *Partial* não deve ter código JavaScript dentro dela. O código deve ficar todo na *View* pai, justamente pra evitar esse tipo de comportamento.

Em segundo lugar, não é uma boa ideia "destruir" código HTML, até porque o HTML não foi projetado para ter dentro dele uma máquina de estados, que é o que você está propondo fazer. Existem *frameworks* que trabalham assim, mas todo o ciclo da aplicação é gerenciado pelo *framework* em si, então possivelmente você teria que reimplementar o sistema todo seguindo as diretrizes deste *framework*.

Em terceiro e último lugar, se o objetivo é ter um sistema se comportando mais ou menos como um SPA (*Single Page Application*), o melhor seria sair do ASP.NET MVC e ir para o Web API. Faria até mais sentido do ponto de vista do comportamento do cliente com a parte do servidor.

Comment: Bem, acredito que você foi um dos poucos a entender meu problema. Obrigado pela resposta. Realmente meu código está cheio de más práticas. Estou apenas fazendo a manutenção do sistema e percebi que existem códigos JavaScript em PartialView que ao serem montadas e depois dispersas o seu código continua "vivo" e interferindo em outras PartialViews.

Comment: Então migre-os para as *Views* pai. Muitos dessas problemas irão desaparecer.

Comment: O problema é que existem elementos em uma PartialView com o mesmo `id` de outra PartialView, mas os eventos não podem ser os mesmos.

Comment: Então gere Ids na hora de abrir a *Partial*, ou simplesmente não use Ids. Use classes.